# Почему не работает мультивыбор для вложенных чекбоксов?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, wordpress

Всем салют! **Контекст**: создать каталог университетов на Wordpress.

**Имеется**:

1. Структура Базы Данных в phpMyAdmin:

   TABLE wp_5pk4xpx5av_universities (
   id INT PRIMARY KEY,
   name VARCHAR(255),
   about TEXT,
   slug VARCHAR(255)
   );
   TABLE wp_5pk4xpx5av_address (
   id INT PRIMARY KEY,
   country VARCHAR(255),
   city VARCHAR(255)
   );
2. Вложенные чекбоксы, которые работают по принципу: если выбран родительский чекбокс "Страна", то активны все вложенные чекбоксы"Город"; если выбран хотя бы один вложенный чекбокс "Город", то активен родительский чекбокс "Страна".

**Что я сделал**: разметку страницы каталога и код для вывода и фильтрации результатов:

```
    <?php
global $wpdb;

// Получение уникальных стран из таблицы адресов
$query_countries = "SELECT DISTINCT country FROM {$wpdb->prefix}address";
$countries = $wpdb->get_col($query_countries);
?>

<form method="GET">
    <?php foreach ($countries as $country) : ?>
        <!-- Основной чекбокс для выбора страны -->
        <input type="checkbox" name="country" value="<?php echo esc_attr($country); ?>" <?php echo (isset($_GET['country']) && $_GET['country'] == $country) ? 'checked' : ''; ?> class="country-checkbox">
        <?php echo esc_html($country); ?><br>

        <?php
        // Получение уникальных городов для выбранной страны
        $query_cities = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT city FROM {$wpdb->prefix}address WHERE country = %s", $country);
        $cities = $wpdb->get_col($query_cities);
        ?>

        <!-- Вложенные чекбоксы для выбора города -->
        <div style="height: 100px; overflow-y: auto; margin-left: 10px;">
            <?php foreach ($cities as $city) : ?>
                <input type="checkbox" name="city" value="<?php echo esc_attr($city); ?>" <?php echo (isset($_GET['city']) && $_GET['city'] == $city) ? 'checked' : ''; ?> class="city-checkbox" data-country="<?php echo esc_attr($country); ?>">
                <?php echo esc_html($city); ?><br>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <br>
    <!-- Кнопка для применения фильтра -->
    <input type="submit" value="Применить фильтр">
</form>

<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var countryCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.country-checkbox');
    var cityCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.city-checkbox');

    // Обработчик события для чекбоксов стран
    countryCheckboxes.forEach(function (countryCheckbox) {
        countryCheckbox.addEventListener('change', function () {
            var country = this.value;
            var cityCheckboxesForCountry = document.querySelectorAll('.city-checkbox[data-country="' + country + '"]');

            // Проверка активации/деактивации чекбоксов городов
            cityCheckboxesForCountry.forEach(function (cityCheckbox) {
                cityCheckbox.checked = countryCheckbox.checked;
            });
        });
    });

    // Обработчик события для чекбоксов городов
    cityCheckboxes.forEach(function (cityCheckbox) {
        cityCheckbox.addEventListener('change', function () {
            var country = this.dataset.country;
            var countryCheckbox = document.querySelector('.country-checkbox[value="' + country + '"]');

            // Проверка активации/деактивации родительского чекбокса страны
            checkParentCountryCheckbox(countryCheckbox);
        });
    });

    // Функция для проверки и установки состояния родительского чекбокса страны
    function checkParentCountryCheckbox(countryCheckbox) {
        var country = countryCheckbox.value;
        var cityCheckboxesForCountry = document.querySelectorAll('.city-checkbox[data-country="' + country + '"]');
        var anyCityCheckboxSelected = false;

        // Проверка, выбран ли хотя бы один чекбокс города
        cityCheckboxesForCountry.forEach(function (cityCheckbox) {
            if (cityCheckbox.checked) {
                anyCityCheckboxSelected = true;
            }
        });

        // Установка состояния родительского чекбокса страны
        countryCheckbox.checked = anyCityCheckboxSelected;
    });

    // Добавляем обработчик для формы
    var filterForm = document.querySelector('form');
    filterForm.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
        // Предотвращаем отправку формы, чтобы обработать ее через AJAX
        event.preventDefault();

        // Ваш код обработки фильтрации, например, использование AJAX
        // ...

        // В этом примере, вы можете использовать функцию filterResults, которую вы определите
        filterResults();
    });

    // Функция для фильтрации результатов
    function filterResults() {
        // Ваш код для фильтрации результатов
        // ...

        // Вывод результатов или отправка запроса на сервер
        alert('Фильтр применен. Обработка результатов...');
    }
});
</script>
```

Для вывода карточек университетов имеется следующий код:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
// Получение данных из таблицы universities и address с объединением по id и фильтрацией
// Фильтрация по стране и городу, если установлены параметры фильтрации
$country_filter = isset($_GET['country']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['country']) : '';
$city_filter = isset($_GET['city']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['city']) : '';

$where_clause = '';

if ($country_filter || $city_filter) {
    $where_clause = 'WHERE ';

    if ($country_filter) {
        $where_clause .= "a.country = '$country_filter'";
    }

    if ($city_filter) {
        if ($country_filter) {
            $where_clause .= ' AND ';
        }
        $where_clause .= "a.city = '$city_filter'";
    }
}

$table_universities = $wpdb->prefix . 'universities';
$table_address = $wpdb->prefix . 'address';

$query = "SELECT u.id, u.name, u.about, a.country, a.city, u.slug
          FROM $table_universities u
          LEFT JOIN $table_address a ON u.id = a.id
          $where_clause";
$universities_data = $wpdb->get_results($query);

// Вывод данных
if ($universities_data) {
    foreach ($universities_data as $university_data) {
        $university_url = esc_url(get_permalink(get_page_by_path('university')) . '?slug=' . $university_data->slug);
?>
        <!-- link university card -->
        <a href="<?php echo $university_url; ?>" id="w-node-_9317e69e-04a2-aa70-fb98-6f892678c56b-d20c27ce" class="card-container bg-color-white">
            <h2 class="text-size-medium">
                <?php echo esc_html($university_data->name); ?>
            </h2>
            <div class="text-size-regular">
                <?php echo esc_html($university_data->about); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="w-layout-vflex tags">
                <div class="w-layout-vflex tag">
                    <div class="text-size-regular">
                        <?php echo esc_html($university_data->country); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="w-layout-vflex tag">
                    <div class="text-size-regular">
                        <?php echo esc_html($university_data->city); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
<?php
    }
} else {
    echo 'No universities found.';
}
?>
<!-- end university card -->
```

**Что я ожидал**: допустим, у вас есть университеты в странах "USA", "UK" и "Canada". При выборе нескольких городов в фильтре, ожидается, что карточки университетов будут отображаться только для выбранных городов в пределах выбранной страны и в адресе страницы отображение соответствующих условий (example.com/?country=USA&city=Pittsfield&city=Lancaster)

```
Для страны USA имеются чекбоксы:
- USA (родительский)
-- Pittsfield (дочерний)
-- Lancaster (дочерний)
-- ... (дочерний)
При выборе города
-- Pittsfield (дочерний)
-- Lancaster (дочерний)
Фильтруется и остаётся активным значение для всех выбранных городов "-- Pittsfield" и "-- Lancaster" и в результатах появляется карточка универа для "-- Pittsfield" и "-- Lancaster" .
```

Что я получил: при выборе двух городов в фильтре для одной страны, после клика на кнопку "Применить" и перезагрузки страницы, я получаю результаты только по последнему чекбоксу в списке вложенных чекбоксов и соответствующую карточку университета из города, который является последним чекбоксом в списке вложенных чекбоксов, а так же в адресе страницы отображение соответствующих условий (example.com/?country=USA&city=Pittsfield&city=Lancaster). Если наглядно, то:

```
Для страны USA имеются чекбоксы:
- USA (родительский)
-- Pittsfield (дочерний)
-- Lancaster (дочерний)
-- ...
При выборе городов
-- Pittsfield (дочерний)
-- Lancaster (дочерний)
Фильтруется и остаётся активным значение для всех выбранных городов "-- Lancaster" и в результатах появляется карточка универа для города, в котором указано значение "-- Lancaster" .
```

**Вопрос**: что добавить/изменить в коде для фильтров, чтобы работал мультивыбор для вложенных чекбоксов? Ведь в адресе страницы существует отображение соответствующих условий (example.com/?country=USA&city=Pittsfield&city=Lancaster), но фильтрованные карточки университетов говорят об обратном. Рабочий аналогичный пример [здесь](https://ischoolconnect.com/en/explore-schools/?limit=10&page=1&sort_key=_score&country=BEL&state=BEL_Flemish%20Brabant&state=BEL_Ottignies-Louvain-la-Neuve).

Comment: Ну как минимум на уровне SQL запроса, у Вас должно быть не `a.city = '$city_filter'`, а `a.city IN ()` где то что в скобках должно быть через запятую. К тому же, несмотря на использование `sanitize_text_field()`, Ваш SQL запрос по прежнему не безопасен, используйте `wpdb::prepare()`.